# ¿Cómo llamar una función de andoid studio desde una aplicación web?

Tags: javascript, android-studio, asp.net

Tengo una función en Android Studio, necesitaba saber como llamar a la función leerMensaje de forma directa desde la web, puede ser de JavaScripts o .Net.

```
 public void leerMensaje(String mensaje)
  {
    //
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(DBDatos.mensaje, mensaje);

  // código para ejecutar mas instrucciones
    
 }
```

Si alguien tiene una idea, se lo agradecería. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: @Bicho, gracias por responder, pero en la pregunta coloque desde una aplicación web, es decir externa como preguntas.
Saludos, espero tu respuesta.

Comment: Y tienes un ejemplo basico de como podría ser?

Comment: Te puede servir: https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/making-android-interacting-with-web-app-921be14f99d8

Answer (score 1):

Lo puede realizar con una [JavascriptInterface](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/JavascriptInterface.html)

No aparenta tener algún problema la creación de la interfaz

```
webView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
//Asigna Interfaz JavaScript
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
webView.loadUrl("http://............../");
```

el método `leerMensaje()` debe ser llamado desde la página que cargas dentro del WebView:

```
  @JavascriptInterface
    public void leerMensaje(String message) {                
        ...
        ...  
        ...
    }
```

Te comparto un ejemplo usando usando un JavascriptInterface:

https://github.com/Jorgesys/Android-Javascriptinterface