# Problema con reproductor Youtube en Android

Tags: android, youtube

tengo un problema, la Api oficial de youtube para android, a desaparecido, por lo cual ellos recomiendan API del reproductor IFrame de YouTube.

Por lo cual ando emigrando mis app a Iframe de Youtube, todo este codigo va perfecto, me carga los videos, pero lo que me falta y no he podido es poder que arranque el metodo del tiempo, cuando se le de play a youtube. Dejo el codigo para que vean

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_resultado_ver_nuevo);

        idpromo = getIntent().getStringExtra("idpromo");

        wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mWebView);



        wv.getSettings();

        wv.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);

        wv.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        wv.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        wv.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        wv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

        wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        final String mimeType = "text/html";
        final String encoding = "UTF-8";
        String html = getHTML(idpromo);

        wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, mimeType, encoding, "");
}

 public String getHTML(String idpromo)
    {

        String html =

                "<html>"
                        + "<body>"

                        + "<div id=\"player\"></div>"

                        + "<script>"

                        + "var tag = document.createElement('script');"

                        + "tag.src = \"https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api\";"
                        + "var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];"
                        + "firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);"



                        + "var player;"
                        + "function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {\n" +
                        "        player = new YT.Player('player', {\n" +
                        "          height: '100%',\n" +
                        "          width: '100%',\n" +
                        "          videoId: '"+idpromo+"',\n" +
                        "          events: {\n" +
                        "            'onReady': onPlayerReady,\n" +

                        "          }\n" +
                        "        });\n" +
                        "      }\n"


                        + "function onPlayerReady(event) {\n" +
                        "        event.target.playVideo();\n" +
                        "      }\n"


                        + "function onPlayerStateChange(event) {\n" +
                        "if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {\n" +
                        "  _startTime();    \n" +
                        "}\n" +
                        "}\n"




        + "</script>"
                        + "</body>"
                        + "</html>";

        return html;

    }

    private void startTime()
    {

        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(tiempo, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                tiempo = millisUntilFinished;
                txt_tiempo.setText(String.valueOf( tiempo / 1000));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

                finish();

             
        }.start();

  

    }
```

El problema es como meter el metodo startTime() dentro de ese codigo html, en la función que detecta el play de youtube, se puede hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo llamar una función de andoid studio desde una aplicación web?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/411558/c%c3%b3mo-llamar-una-funci%c3%b3n-de-andoid-studio-desde-una-aplicaci%c3%b3n-web). [Otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10389678/13419694).